# Ruby On Rails не подключается nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Добрый день. Подключаю Nokogiri по этой [инструкции](http://webbackend.blogspot.ru/2012/10/nokogiri-ruby-on-rails.html).

1. Добавляю `gem 'nokogiri'` в гемфайл
2. В консоли `bundle install`
3. В контроллере:

   require 'open-uri'

   require 'nokogiri'

И после этого шага если открыть страницу получаю ошибку:

```
cannot load such file -- nokogiri
```

Не могу понять где допустил ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

Попробовал еще раз по мануалу с [nokogiri.org](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html), все встало.

Только зависимости ставил без судо:

```
# ruby developer packages
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev ruby1.8 ri1.8 rdoc1.8 irb1.8
sudo apt-get install libreadline-ruby1.8 libruby1.8 libopenssl-ruby

# nokogiri requirements
apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: ;D А не лучше ли для этого использоваь rvm.io?

curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm requirements

Answer (score 0):

```
class ParserController < ApplicationController

  # для получения контента через http
  require 'open-uri'

  # подключаем Nokogiri
  require 'nokogiri'

  def yandex
    source = 'http://catalog.yandex.ru/'

    # получаем содержимое веб-страницы в объект
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(source, 'User-Agent' => 'FireFox'))

    # производим поиск по элементам с помощью css-выборки
    page.css('a.b-rubric__list__item__link').each do |link|
      data = Hash.new
      data['text'] = link.content
      data['href'] = link['href']
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: Всё так, ошибка происходит при require 'nokogiri'. Зависимости поставил как написано тут http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Comment: Навскидку: удалите ваш Gemfile.lock и сделайте снова bundle install